# vb net DataGridView Sort Column order based on Cell Value

Tags: datagridview, multiple-columns, datagridviewcolumn

I've got a DataGridView with multiple columns, each column contains 4 rows.
The columns are created by iterate over a collecting of files within a specific folder, each file get's his own column.
After all columns are created I like to sort them based on the string value in row 4.
Let me be clear that I want to sort the Column order, not the rows on the column.
I can't find the correct sort command for that action, did it exist?
Otherwise, do I need to change/reset the index from the columns based on a list with the collected string value?

Comment: I am confident that you will have to set the column order yourself. I am unaware of any `DataGridView` “command/property” that will sort the columns based on a row value.

Comment: Thanks John for your reaction, think your right. How would you rearrange the columns?

Comment: You should re-word the last sentence in the last comment to read… _”How would “I” rearrange the columns?”_ … Assuming the data is already in the grid… then you will need to loop through all the columns at row four (4) to determine which column is the first column, second column…etc. Bear in mind that you will most likely need to store this column order info. Once stored simply set each column to the proper display order `dataGridView1.Columns[x].DisplayOrder = y;`. It is unclear what criteria determines the column order therefore an example may be superfluous.

Comment: I consider going back to my previous method, fill the DGV based on another DGV where a sorted column already exists.